# Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid prepareCollection depends on action called before gridAction

Tags: magento-1.7, collection

i've got a problem in my customgrid while preparing the collection data. The grid is used by 2 actions with different collections, xyAction uses an innerjoin while abAction uses a leftJoin in prepareCellection:

```
class Abc_Mymodul_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Invoice_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    ..
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
    ....
        if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'xy')
        {
            $collection->getSelectSql()->join(array('a' => Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'mydata'), 'main_table.increment_id = a.mydata_id');
        }
        else if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'ab')
        {
            $collection->getSelectSql()->joinLeft(array('a' => Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'mydata'), 'main_table.increment_id = a.mydata_id');
        }
    ....
    }    
}
```

This works fine with the above actions but not with the gridAction, which is called by sorting or filtering in the grid.

Does anyone have a hint, how to handle this in gridAction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I advice you do not base your choice in `_prepareCollection()` on controller's action. In layout xml where you define your block you can set some option for different collections

```
<layout_handle>
    <block type="abc_mymodul/adminhtml_sales_invoice_grid">
        <action method="setCollectionType"><value>xy</value></action>
    </block>
</layout_handle>
```

Now in `_prepareCollection()` you can do something like this

```
class Abc_Mymodul_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Invoice_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    ..
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
    ....
        if ($this->getCollectionType() == 'xy')
        {
            $collection->getSelectSql()->join(array('a' => Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'mydata'), 'main_table.increment_id = a.mydata_id');
        } else {
            $collection->getSelectSql()->joinLeft(array('a' => Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'mydata'), 'main_table.increment_id = a.mydata_id');
        }
        ....
    }    
}
```

As for `gridAction` you can can create two different grid actions in your controller
`gridForXyAction` and `gridForAbAction`.

```
public function gridForXyAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('abc_mymodul/adminhtml_sales_invoice_grid')
             ->setCollectionType('xy')
             ->toHtml()
    );
}

public function gridForAbAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('abc_mymodul/adminhtml_sales_invoice_grid')
             ->toHtml()
    );
}
```

Then according to `CollectionType` attribute you can define for grid different ajax actions in `getGridUrl()`.

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    if ($this->getCollectionType() == 'xy') {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/gridForXy', array('_current'=>true));
    } else {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/gridForAb', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

And my last advice. Try not to use one grid for different collections. If you cannot avoid that do not make your grid be dependent on controller action, use setting grid attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the advice. I'll try your solution!